# Is it possible to get the visitors details including the details of the page they are coming from?

Tags: php, email

I am working on a project where I am sending daily emails to my clients, These emails contain the details of the pages they want to visit. Now what I am looking to do is that when the user visits these suggested pages, their details gets stored in the database.

For example, I have sent www.example.com/test as an email to many of my clients, Now when one of these client visits the page www.example.com/test, it gets the details of the visitor and the log of this visit gets stored.

```
No | email       | visits | time               |
1  |abc@test.com |   1    |20-04-2016 10:00:05 |
2  |xyz@test.com |   3    |20-04-2016 11:00:05 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take this information from $_SERVER var

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

> $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] - The address of the page (if any) which
>   referred the user agent to the current page

Answer (score 0):

yeah its simple man follow my step

step 1 :while mail sent you just add the your own page link like this

```
<a href="own_page.php?id=<?php echo any unique user id ?>&original_link=<?php echo facebook.com ?>" >click here</a>
```

step 2: when user click the link your page navigate so there you do update using      user unique id and then redirect him to original link that's all.

Comment: just to elaborate the answer: when you are sending emails or sharing links on social media you should exactly know which link is sent where. So you can add the referrer link at the end of the link (*either by query as mentioned in the answer or by using hash*). Then on your landing page via javascript or server side script - you can have the referrer.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible.

There are various methods of doing this.

1. If your users need to log in before seeing content then you can log the user's details just after they have logged in when they access the content.
2. If the content is publicly accessible then when you generate your emails to send to your users you can append a GET variable to uniquely identify the URL you sent to specific users. For example you can send `www.example.com/test?ref=xyz`. When the user accesses the page test then you can have some code to check the `ref` GET variable and match it against the values you have in your database which will link it to the user you sent it to. Of course if your users send the links to each other then there may be misleading information. It depends on how accurate you would like the data.

However since the web is open to anyone with a web browser, the most accurate method is to make the content accessible only by authentication.